# IIS How to config to hide files in the folder?

Tags: iis, iis-8

For example, my website's url is http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/index.aspx

If someone enters `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` at browser, the page will show my files in server:

[image]

What shouled I config to hide this file-list page?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for disabling directory browsing. You can follow below steps to disable directory browsing in IIS.

1. Navigate to your application in IIS Manager and select it.
2. In Features View, double-click Directory Browsing.
3. In the Actions pane, click Disable if the Directory Browsing feature is enabled.